# Somatório Multithead

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um somatório multithread porem o valor esta muito discrepante: o valor que deveria ser a soma de todos os numeros `499500` o que está sendo o resultado: `1561250`

Classe Principal:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Ex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        int soma = 0;
        int qtd = 250;
        int inicio = 0;
        int qtdThreads = 4;
        int qtdValores = 1000;
        int[] a = new int[qtdValores];
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdValores; i++){
            a[i] = i;
        }

         //cria pool de threads para execução de tarefas
        ThreadPoolExecutor p = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 10, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));
        List<Soma> listThread = new ArrayList<Soma>();

        for(int i = 0; i < qtdThreads; i++){
            listThread.add(new Soma(a,inicio));
            p.submit(listThread.get(i));
            inicio += qtd;
        }

        //força a execução e finalização das threads
        p.shutdown();

        //aguarda finalização das threads em execução
        p.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        for(int i = 0; i < qtdThreads; i++){
            soma += listThread.get(i).soma;
        }

        System.out.println(soma);
    }

}
```

Classe de Soma:

```
public class Soma extends Thread{
    private int qtd = 250;
    public int inicio;
    public int soma = 0;
    public int[] a;

    public Soma(int[] a, int inicio){
        this.a = a;
        this.inicio = inicio;
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int i = inicio; i < i + qtd;i++){
            soma += a[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = inicio; i < i + qtd;i++){` Esse trecho está certo? O que ele deveria fazer?

Comment: começar o somatorio em determinada posisção de inicio (pois varias threads estão realizando a soma em inicios dierentes) e parando na ultima posição antes da posição de inicio da proxima thread somar

Comment: Ainda não entendi seu código, mas você tá ligado que para sair desse `for` a variável `qtd` deverá ser de `0` para baixo, não tá? E eu não vejo a variável `qtd` sendo modificada em nenhum lugar após a inicialização.

Comment: qtd não é para ser modificada em local algum, e esta saindo do for.

Comment: @Math este `qtd` é a quantidade de valores do vetor a serem lidos e somados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no seguinte trecho de código:

```
public void run(){
    for(int i = inicio; i < i + qtd;i++){
        soma += a[i];
    }
}
```

Você deve fazer:

```
public void run(){
    for(int i = inicio; i < inicio + qtd;i++){
        soma += a[i];
    }
}
```

Pois você assumiu que ele deve percorrer desde o inicio até o inicio mais a quantidade, mas ao usar `i` ao invés de `inicio` seu valor que deveria ser o inicial fica variando a cada iteração.

Comment: Puts, verdade foi erro de principiante.